# Access to matched terms in java native scripting

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am using elasticsearch engine and I don’t want to use elastic scoring algorithm (TF/IDF) for scoring and sorting my document so I use java native script for implement my own scoring algorithm. I use multi_match query with fuzziness 2 and I need terms that match to my query in my java native script. How can I access them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access them via `doc` values. Check [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) for more

```
import  org.elasticsearch.common.logging.*;
ESLogger logger = ESLoggerFactory.getLogger('SCRIPT_NAME');

def str = doc['FIELD_HERE'].values.join(' ');
logger.info('Value: ' + str);
```

Comment: doc['field_name'].values give all terms in a field but i need only terms that matched to my query